# Drop boolean rows based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df from which I need to delete certain rows.

How could I drop all rows where NIT is true and the rest are all false? And the same for FIB?

Drop all rows like these:

```
number ISM  AAAL    GSOG    GSI     AN      NIT     FIB
2     FALSE FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
222   FALSE FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
```

Comment: If my answer satisfies you, please mark it as an answer, so that other users can see that it answers the question.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in one step so that I only have one dataframe after deleting the rows?

Comment: Sure, you can just add all conditions into one line, but it harms readability.

Comment: `df = df.drop(df[(df['NIT'] & ~df.drop('NIT', axis=1).all(axis=1)) | (df['FIB'] & ~df.drop('FIB', axis=1).all(axis=1))].index)`

Comment: Thanks sorry. Is there an easy way to delete if NIT is false and (the rest is false or the rest except FIB is false?) And the same for FIB, all in one line?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but from your description I assume that smth. like this:
`df = df.drop(df[((df.drop(['NIT','FIB'], axis=1).all(axis=1)) & (~df['NIT'] | ~df['FIB']) )].index)`

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake, try this, please:
`df = df.drop(df[((df.drop(['NIT','FIB'], axis=1).all(axis=1)) | (~df['NIT'] & ~df['FIB']) )].index)`

Comment: Or, you can simplify this to be `df = df[~df.drop(['NIT','FIB'], axis = 1).all(axis=1) & ~df[['NIT','FIB']].all(axis=1)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mask_NIT_true = df['NIT']
mask_all_exc_NIT_false = ~df.drop('NIT', axis=1).all(axis=1)
df = df.drop(df[mask_NIT_true & mask_all_exc_NIT_false].index)
```

```
mask_FIB_true = df['FIB']
mask_all_exc_FIB_false = ~df.drop('FIB', axis=1).all(axis=1)
df = df.drop(df[mask_FIB_true & mask_all_exc_FIB_false].index)
```